# IPython.parallel - can I write my own log into the engine logs?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ipython

I'd like to be able to log outputs from the functions I pass to my engines in the relevant engine logs.

I.e.:

```
data = /* my list of data to operate on */
def fn(inval):
    import logging
    log = logging.getLogger()
    log.error('This is on the engine')
    // do stuff
    return result

calculated_data = []
for datum in data:
    calc = view.apply(fn, datum)
    calculated_data.append(calc)
```

I'd like to be able to see the log statements in the relevant engine log that operated on the specific task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grab the logger of the current app (i.e. the engine in this case) with:

```
from IPython.config import Application
log = Application.instance().log
```

Then log as normal, and it will go to the engine logs.

Comment: Would it be possible to forward logs to the master process, to reach stdout through a console handler?