# logging with IPython parallel

Tags: python, logging, ipython, ipython-parallel

I am trying to setup logging when using IPython parallel. Specifically, I would like to redirect log messages from the engines to the client. So, rather than each of the engines logging  individually to their own log files, as in [IPython.parallel - can I write my own log into the engine logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146168/ipython-parallel-can-i-write-my-own-log-into-the-engine-logs/15146477#15146477), I am looking for something like [How should I log while using multiprocessing in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641420/how-should-i-log-while-using-multiprocessing-in-python)

Based on reviewing the IPython code base, I have the impression that the way to do this would be to register a zmq.log.hander.PUBHandler with the logging module (see documentation in iploggerapp.py). I have tried this in various ways, but none seem to work. I also tried to register a logger via IPython.parallel.util. connect_engine_logger, but this also does not appear to do anything.

**update**

I have made some progress on this problem. If I specify in ipengine_config c.IPEngineApp.log_url, then the logger of the IPython application has the appropriate EnginePubHandler. I checked this via

```
%%px
from IPython.config import Application
log = Application.instance().log 
print(log.handlers)
```

Which indicated that the application logger has an EnginePUBHandler for each engine. Next, I can start the iplogger app in a separate terminal and see the log messages from each engine.

However, What I would like to achieve is to see these log messages in the notebook, rather than in a separate terminal. I have tried starting iplogger from within the notebook via a system call, but this crashes.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work in the notebook?

Comment: How/where do I find the "iplogger app"?